# Getting input via input stream and storing it in a structure variables

Tags: c++

I am receiving user input via inputstream and am storing it in a array, the below code describes my scenario:

```
istringstream iss(line);
 // The below code is incorrect 
  while (iss >> i)
{

    image[j].r = i;
    image[j].g = i;// this should be the next character 
    image[j].b = i;// this should be the character after the previous one 
    j++
}
```

**Problem**: I want to read in the characters 3 at a time and store them in my array structure. How can I achieve this?

Note: image is an array of a certain kind of structures

Comment: _"incase you have any questions please mention them in the comments"_ Nope. You make your question as clear as possible beforehand. Long comment threads aren't helpful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes you are right, i have tried making my question as clear as possible, and i realized to make it more robust- i had to let out a lot of implementation details i was using and didn't want to too that

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what you said makes sense, removed that line and made it as clear as i could

Comment: Probably you want something like `while (iss >> image[j].r >> image[j].g >> image[j].b)`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ will try this

Comment: Do or do not. There is no try. Fortunately, and unlike most Force tricks, @πάνταῥεῖ 's solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just read the values you want directly:

```
size_t j = 0;
istringstream iss(line);

while (iss >> image[j].r >> image[j].g >> image[j].b) {
   j++;
}
```

You need to ensure that `image` is big enough to hold all the values read.

---

The probably more flexible solution would be to use a `std::vector` instead of a raw array:

```
istringstream iss(line);
std::vector<MyStruct> image;

MyStruct item;
while (iss >> item.r >> item.g >> item.b) {
   image.push_back(item);
}
```